# $cacheFactory using custom service

Tags: javascript, angularjs

we have use $cacheFactory for get some configuration and User data one time 
like

```
var cache = $cacheFactory("Temp");

    var getCachedData = function (url) {

        var data = cache.get(url);

        var deferred = $q.defer();

        if (data) {
            deferred.resolve(data);
        } else {
            readFromServer(url).then(function(result) {
                cache.put(url, result);
                deferred.resolve(result);
            });
        }
        return deferred.promise;
    };

    return {
        GetCachedData: getCachedData
    };
```

If services get data as null then it give call to server ow it will return data from Cache but if second call come be four fist complete then he give server call so how can we use **lock** like C# in JavaScript      .

Answer (score 1):

To avoid to make multiple call to the same API, you need to make something like that (I didn't test but this should work) :

```js
var isRetrievingData = false;
var waitingDeferred = [];

var getData = function (url) {
    var data = cache.get(url);

    var deferred = $q.defer();

    if (data) {
        deferred.resolve(data);
    } else if (isRetrievingData) {
        waitingDeferred.push(deferred);
    } else {
        isRetrievingData = true;
        waitingDeferred.push(deferred);
      
        readFromServer(url).then(function(result) {
            cache.put(url, result);
            
            for(var i = 0; i < waitingDeferred.length; i++) {
                waitingDeferred[i].resolve(result);
            }
        });
    }
    return deferred.promise;
};
```

Here how it works :

- If the data is already cached, just return it by resolving the deferred
- If the data is not cached and `isRetrievingData` is false, launch the request and set `isRetrievingData` to true
- If the data is not cached and `isRetrievingData` is true, that means that another call is in progress so don't to anything, just add the deferred in an array

When the only call is finished, to send data to each caller, you have just to resolve each deferred registered in the `waitingDeferred` array.

Is that good for you ?

Comment: If this answer solved your problem, could you mark it as answered ?